# ng new project gives Audit warnings

Tags: angular

I might be wrong and obviously not understanding how angular works, but if I do `ng new test-proj`, add routing yes and scss, with latest lts i'd expect to see that `npm audit` prints eg. "All OK".

But I get:

```
Found 13 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 7 high) in 1310 scanned packages
  13 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

`ng version` yields the following:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.9
Node: 14.18.1
Package Manager: npm 6.14.15
OS: linux x64

Angular: 12.2.9
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.9
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.9
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.9
@schematics/angular             12.2.9
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

Do I have som version clashes or is there some other update command I could run so that `ng new test_proj` creates a project with no vulnerabilities?

Comment: Check full audit report and try to upgrade packages that have vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NPM Audit Fix**

- Run the `npm audit` command
- Scroll until you find a line of text
  separating two issues
- Manually run the command given in the text to
  upgrade one package at a time, e.g. `npm i --save-dev jest@24.8.0`
- After upgrading a package make sure to check for breaking changes
  before upgrading the next package
- Avoid running `npm audit fix --force`

**Vulnerabilities**:
Every now and then after installing your projects dependencies, `npm i`, you will be met with an error from **NPM** that looks something like

`┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ braces                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ jest [dev]                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ jest > jest-cli > micromatch > braces                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/786                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
found 62 low severity vulnerabilities in 20610 scanned packages</span62 vulnerabilities require semver-major dependency updates.`

This is actually an extremely small example of a typical vulnerability warning. As you can see from the text underneath the vulnerability it says

`found 62 low severity vulnerabilities in 20610 scanned packages 62 vulnerabilities require semver-major dependency updates.`

Meaning that this example would have another 61 vulnerabilities ranging from `low` to `high` with of course `high` being the most dangerous vulnerability. For more info on any of these vulnerabilities, there is also a link to the vulnerability on **NPM** inside the `More Info` section of the warning.

At first, it may seem confusing on how to properly fix these vulnerabilities. **NPM** actually provides a service built into **NPM** that is supposed to automatically fix these issues, `npm audit fix`, but I've found that this will rarely work, and will leave you with nearly just as many vulnerabilities as before. In fact, here's an example of what happened after I ran `npm audit fix`.

```
fixed 0 of 62 vulnerabilities in 20610 scanned packages
1 package update for 62 vulns involved breaking changes
(use `npm audit fix --force` to install breaking changes; or refer to `npm audit` for steps to fix these manually)
```

**NPM** gives us the option to use the `--force` flag, `npm audit fix --force`, but even **NPM** will warn you about using this flag

**To Fix:**

**1. Update dependent packages if a fix exists**

**Manually upgrade the packages one at a time with the command suggested by NPM instead of running the `npm audit fix --force` command. For example `npm install --save-dev jest@24.8.0`.**
**Fix the vulnerability**:
If a fix does not exist, you may want to suggest changes that address the vulnerability to the package maintainer in a pull or merge request on the package repository.

1. Check the "Path" field for the location of the vulnerability.
2. On the [npm public registry](https://npmjs.com/), find the package with the vulnerability.
   For more information on finding packages, see "[Searching for and
   choosing packages to download](https://docs.npmjs.com/searching-for-and-choosing-packages-to-download)".
3. In the package repository, open a
   pull or merge request to make the fix on the package repository.
4. Once the fix is merged and the package has been updated in the npm
   public registry, update your copy of the package that depends on the
   package with the fix.

**2. Open an issue in the package or dependent package issue tracker**:
If you do not want to fix the vulnerability or update the dependent package yourself, open an issue in the package or dependent package issue tracker.

1. On the [npm public registry](https://npmjs.com/), find the package with the vulnerability.
   For more information on finding packages, see "[Searching for and
   choosing packages to download](https://docs.npmjs.com/searching-for-and-choosing-packages-to-download)".
2. In the package or dependent package issue tracker, open an issue and
   include information from the audit report, including the
   vulnerability report from the "More info" field.

**3. No security vulnerabilities found**:
If no security vulnerabilities are found, this means that packages with known vulnerabilities were not found in your package dependency tree. Since the advisory database can be updated at any time, we recommend regularly running `npm audit` manually, or adding `npm audit` to your continuous integration process.
[image: https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/securing-your-code/audit-no-vulnerabilities.png]

**4. Turning off `npm audit` on package installation**:

**Installing a single package:**

To turn off `npm audit` when installing a single package, use the `--no-audit` flag:

```
npm install example-package-name --no-audit
```

**Installing all packages:**

To turn off `npm audit` when installing all packages, set the `audit` setting to `false` in your user and global `npmrc` config files:

```
npm set audit false
```

Comment: Let's I run this pattern and successfully receive no warnings. Can i somehow make that my default template when i create a new project? What if there is no fix for the package? Should i just avoid angular and wait for an update which fixes the issues? If i run --save-dev I might break dependency to other packages? Will I be warned if that happens? I guess that I could be rnuning --save-dev for hours and in the end still not have an environment that gives me 0 warnings?

Comment: @user3532232 By default while creating new project in Angular CLI i am sure about that you can't do the `npm audit`

Comment: What if there is no fix for the package? Should i just avoid using angular and wait for an update which fixes the issue? If i run --save-dev and downgrade I might break dependency to other packages? Will I be warned if that happens? I guess that I could be running --save-dev and downgrade packages for hours and in the end still not have an environment that gives me 0 warnings?

Comment: @user3532232 You should not worry about this unless you happen to be using one or more of the packages that have vulnerabilities. All angular developers see those warnings, and ignore them unless something comes up. You can run `npm audit` to check which packages are affected, then either upgrade or avoid importing them.

Comment: So only if i actually import the modules in a .ts file I will be affected by the warning?

Comment: @user3532232 No it wont affect anything with in your project. When you have issues with packages automattically you will get an build error. So dont worry about the issue. Its normal when you go with npm packages.

Answer (score 2):

> Found 13 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 7 high) in 1310 scanned packages

You should not worry about this unless you happen to be using one or more of the packages that have vulnerabilities. These are just standard warnings; don't expect "All Ok!" because node goes out of its way to check for anything. It is up to the maintainers of those packages to update them, but with 1310 packages it's inevitable some will have warnings.

Comment: So how do I check that I use a package? Is it if I have an actual import? Otherwise It's just a warning that says if you import the module your site will be effected by the error?

Comment: Not an error, a warning. All angular developers see those warnings, and ignore them unless something comes up. As per other answers, you can run ``npm audit`` to check which packages are affected, then either upgrade or avoid importing them.

Answer (score 0):

install the [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates). It automaticcaly upgrades.

run `ncu`
then run `ncu -u` to upgrade.

Check the git repo for more information, 
https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates#readme